# Interpolation of panel data based on a flag column in r

Tags: r, dplyr, interpolation, panel

I have a time-series panel dataset which is structured in the following way:

```
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L),
  id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  c = c(11L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 15L),
flag = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
)

#>   year id  c flag
#> 1 2012  1 11 FALSE
#> 2 2013  1 26 TRUE
#> 3 2014  1 13 FALSE
#> 4 2012  2 16 FALSE
#> 5 2013  2 15 FALSE
#> 6 2014  2 19 FALSE
```

I want to do a linear interpolation where the value in column c is interpolated by averaging the value before and after it whenever there is a corresponding TRUE value in the flag column. e.g. since the value 26 has a TRUE flag I want it to be replaced with the average of 11 and 13 which is 12.
I tried to write a function but I have a bit of trouble implementing it properly in the panel data setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `replace` `c` values where `flag` is `TRUE` with `NA` and then interpolate values with `na.approx` from `zoo`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(c = zoo::na.approx(replace(c, flag, NA)))

#  year id  c  flag
#1 2012  1 11 FALSE
#2 2013  1 12  TRUE
#3 2014  1 13 FALSE
#4 2012  2 16 FALSE
#5 2013  2 15 FALSE
#6 2014  2 15 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What's the easiest way to replace the values with TRUE flag to NA in column c?

Comment: I have done that using `replace` statement above. You can also do `df$c[df$flag] <- NA`.

Answer (score 0):

One option that pops to mind is to use a subsetted `?stats::filter`, which essentially is a moving average based on multiplying the values either side by 0.5, and the current value by 0.

```
df$c[df$flag] <- stats::filter(df$c, c(0.5,0,0.5))[df$flag]
df

#  year id  c  flag
#1 2012  1 11 FALSE
#2 2013  1 12  TRUE
#3 2014  1 13 FALSE
#4 2012  2 16 FALSE
#5 2013  2 15 FALSE
#6 2014  2 15 FALSE
```